# Invalid SSL cert using /etc/hosts

Tags: tls, certificates

I have certificate for a.com that has two alternative domains: *.b.com and c.com. When I have the following in my /etc/hosts:

```
<IP_OF_test.b.com> b.com
```

If I then enter https://b.com in my browser, I would expect the server behind *.b.com to accept it but it gives the `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error despite showing me that the certificate is for `a.com` and has the two alternative domains `*.b.com` and `c.com`

Am I trying to do something that is impossible?

The reason I need to be able to make something like this work is because I have a PhoneGap app, of which I don't have the source code, so the only way to test it (besides simply testing it in production) is to use a DNS spoofing app that redirects my `b.com` requests to `test.b.com`, but I can't get past the SSL certificate (on PC I can just accept the certificate, but no such luck for a PhoneGap app).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A certificate which includes `a.com`, `*.b.com` and `c.com` is valid only for subdomains of `b.com` (i.e. `www.b.com`) but not for `b.com` itself. The certificate would need to explicitly include `b.com` for this.

Comment: D'oh, didn't know that, thanks :-)